# How to snap to right angles 90 degree using quaternions

Tags: javascript, quaternions, angle, babylonjs

I have some direction quaternion 'CurrentQ'.

I can save it as reference 'RefQ'

I want to snap updated CurrentQ to RefQ and all RefQ 90 degree rotations (totally 6 angles) if the difference between angles will be small.

something like:

```
if(Math.abs(CurrentQ.x-RefQ.x)<0.05 && ....) CurrentQ=RefQ;
```

Performance is important.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this:

1. create unit axis vectors for all 6 snap rotations
2. rotete 6 axis vectors with reference quaternion RefQ
3. make current direction vector ( unit vector that is rotated with CurrentQ )
4. check distances between current direction vector and each of 6 axis vectors from 2)

I will upload code and application in few days